# When running via maven, my tests are not found in the junit project

Tags: selenium, pom.xml, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nFOk.png)

As in the screenshot 1 I'm trying to run my set of autotests, the build works successfully, but not a single test is defined.

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6R7P.png)

Screenshot 2 shows the result after running through maven

If you run tests separately, through "run test", but everything starts and runs according to the script

my POM file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>src/test/java/</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>`
```

I want that tests were defined in all classes.
I tried to play with the pom file, apparently there are problems in it, but nothing happens.

[link to project](https://github.com/DmitriyShvedov/Java_QA/blob/main/Test_Framework/pom.xml)

Answer (score 0):

i fix problem

my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Test_Framework</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <selenium.version>4.6.0</selenium.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).